# Haskell char quotes

Tags: haskell, char, quotes

I've started to learn haskell for real recently, and I'm doing some exercises from [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_about_lists).
I'm doing exercise with RLE encoding, and I've come with solution like this:

```
import Data.List
rle :: String -> [(Int,Char)]
rle [] = []
rle xs = zip lengths chars
        where
        groups = group xs
        lengths = map length groups
        chars = map head groups

rle_toString :: [(Int, Char)] -> String
rle_toString [] = []
rle_toString (x:xs) = show (fst x ) ++ show (snd x) ++ rle_toString xs`
```

Not a very elegant solution, but it almost works. The problem is, that I get output like this: `"7'a'8'b'7'j'6'q'3'i'7'q'1'p'1'a'16'z'2'n'"`. The single quotes with chars are not vetry elegant. How can I achieve output like: `"7a8b7j6q3i7q1p1a16z2n"`?

Comment: With that output, how would you decode "12345"?

Comment: @augustss: This task assumes that input has no numbers.

Comment: Fair enough.  BTW, you don't need a special case for `[]`, also the `zip` can be replaced by a `map` over `group`, especially using `Control.Arrow.&&&`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`show` is used to print values as they appear in Haskell source code, and thus puts single quotes around characters (and double quotes around strings, and so on). Use `[snd x]` instead to show just the character.

In Haskell, `String` is just shorthand for List of Char `[Char]`. For example, the String `"Foo"` can also be written like this: `['F','o','o']`. So, to convert a single character to a string, just put in in brackets: `[char]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of `show` on a character. `show 'a' == "'a'"`.

The solution is to realize that strings are just lists of characters, so if `c` is a character, then the one-character string that contains `c` is just `[c]`.