# Haskell instance show char without single quotes

Tags: haskell

This is what I tried so far

```
data Expr = Var Char

instance Show Expr where
  show (Var x) = show x
```

Variables should be printed as their single-character name.
e.g. (Var 'x') prints as x

This is the output i get:

```
*Test> (Var 'x')
'x'
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Side note, but the output of `show` is meant to be valid Haskell source that can be read back in with `read` to result in the same thing you originally showed. If you're wanting to pretty print expressions it'd be better to make a pretty printing function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell char quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180617/haskell-char-quotes)

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that `String` is an alias for `[Char]`:

```
instance Show Expr where
  show (Var x) = [x]
```